# How do I set the value of an IBOutlet define in a superclass from a subclass in Swift?

Tags: cocoa, swift3, nstableview

I am working on an app that has a number of similar, but not identical views, each of which contains an NSTableView.

I have a base view controller class that implements methods common to all of my view controllers (AppViewController). It inherits from NSViewController.

I have another view controller base class (ListViewController) that inherits from AppViewController. It conforms to NSWindowDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, and NSTableViewDelegate, and implements all of the methods common to my list views.

The ListViewController defines an IBOutlet for the table view.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
```

This outlet has not been wired to the storyboard.

I am working on a sub-class of ListViewController that implements the details for one case.

The subclass defines its own IBOutlet for the actual table view. This IBOutlet *is* wired to the storyboard.

The viewDidLoad() method of this class attempts to use that value to set the IBOutlet defined in ListViewController.

```
class Clv: ListViewController<CustomerMaster>
{
  @IBOutlet weak var customersTableView: NSTableView!

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    tableView = customersTableView
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

This compiles just fine but fails at run-time with:

> 017-08-29 08:16:44.602374-0700 Inventory[6910:156206640] Unknown class
>   _TtC9Inventory3Clv in Interface Builder file at path /.../DerivedData/Inventory-begbsguxpczpiebmygowechkthaw/Build/Products/Debug/Inventory.app/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc/CustomerListWindowController.nib.
>
> 2017-08-29 08:16:44.803674-0700 Inventory[6910:156206640] Failed to
>   connect (customersTableView) outlet from (NSViewController) to
>   (NSTableView): missing setter or instance variable

I suspect that my approach is rather naive, but have been unable to find another approach through various searches.

One other oddity that I have noticed is that when I try to specify the class for the view controller on the storyboard, my Clv class is not in the list. That is probably related to the failure to connect error.

TIA.

**Additional information:**

```
class AppViewController: NSViewController { ... }

class ListViewController<Model: RestModel>: AppViewController,
                                            NSWindowDelegate,
                                            NSTableViewDataSource,
                                            NSTableViewDelegate     { ... }
```

RestModel is a protocol.

Comment: It looks like you haven’t set the subclass of your view controller in the storyboard. The error is trying to connect the IBOutlet property to `NSViewController`.

Comment: Also... how is ListViewController defined? Is CustomerMaster a generic type?

Comment: @Fogmeister, Yeah. That's what I figured, too. I did set the class, but Xcode didn't seem to like it. My subclass is not listed in the class pull-down on the storyboard so I entered it manually. See the last paragraph of my expanded description.

Comment: can you show the definition of ListViewController and also explain what CustomerMaster is.

Comment: @fogmeister, Please see the additional info I just added. Thx

Comment: ok thanks. I’m not 100% certain. I’ll have to check but not sure if the generic requirement is causing this?

Comment: The problem is definitely coming from the fact that you can’t set the subclass. In the error it is trying to connect your table view outlet to an NSViewController. We just need to work out why you can’t set the subclass.

Comment: That makes sense. I am assuming that the first error ( Unknown class _TtC9Inventory3Clv) was caused by my setting the class manually in the storyboard. This looks like some sort of mangled name like C++ might create.

Comment: Is the class defined on the top level of the source file it's in, or is it nested within some other type?

Comment: Also, if you try to set an Objective-C name for the class manually via adding something like `@objc(MyObjCClassName)` in front of the class definition, does that fix your issue?

Comment: The classes are all defined at the top level of their source files.   The compiler won't let me add an @objc() to the subclass. It says "Generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' attribute because they are not directly visible from Objective-C"